# Cameras in Voyager probes 2017

Tags: optics, visible-light, camera, space-mission, astrophotography

Riffing off an old thread...

Analog v digital and data transmission aside, I'm wondering how images were captured in such low light at 37,000+mph. Seems like a wide open aperture and slow shutter would capture a very blurry image at that speed.

Anyone read the specs that can answer?

Comment: Which images are you referring to?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty the question title implies to pictures taken by the Voyager in 2017.

Comment: Neither Voyager probe has taken any pictures for a long time: more than twenty years in fact.  So I am not sure what the '2017' refers to.  With regards to motion blurring, you may want to consider that the objects photographed by spacecraft are usually quite a long way away.

Comment: Voyager spacecraft were reprogrammable, and for its final planetary pictures, it was programmed to do a) a long exposure, and b) move the camera to always be pointing at the planet, to avoid the blur that would be present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, neither Voyager spacecraft has taken any images in a long time: the last images taken by the Voyager spacecraft were the ['family portrait'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_Portrait_(Voyager)) of the solar system, taken in 1990:

[image]

<sup>[Image source](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/photo_gallery/photogallery-solarsystem.html)</sup>

This is confirmed by the [instrument panel](https://voyager.jpl.nasa.gov/mission/status/) of the mission status page. The probes no longer have enough electrical power available to either take new images or beam them back.

Nevertheless, your question still applies. Voyager 1 is currently travelling, as you note, at $60\,000\:\rm{km/h}$; in 1990 it was at about 40 AU from the Sun (as opposed to 140 AU now), which turns out to make only a negligible effect on its speed. That sounds pretty fast, but keep in mind that it is imaging objects that are at astronomical distances from it: even if you keep the aperture open for an entire day, so that the spacecraft moves about 1.4 million km during the exposure, that's still about a hundred times less than the Earth-Sun distance and therefore about 4000 times less than Voyager's distance from the Sun. At solar-system length scales, even to imaging precision, Voyager hardly moved during the exposure time.

(Once you go into [the details](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/photo_gallery/caption/solar_family.txt), you get that the exposures were much shorter than that: the mosaic uses a range of exposure times, from 0.005 s to 15s, where the longer 15 s exposures were used for the Uranus and Neptune frames, which [do show some slight blurring](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/image/planetary/solar_system/family_portraits.jpg) caused by the spacecraft motion. But that's about all it does, really.)